# Alternative when document.URL doesn't work for redirected domain?

Tags: javascript, dns

I want to identify in Javascript the URL that the user sees in the address bar.  But when I use document.URL the resulting value is the original domain name and not the domain the user sees.

I am doing the domain forwarding through my godaddy account settings.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. If the url is rewritten on the server, javascript, which runs on the client, has absolutely no way of getting the actual url. You can only get the url which is visible in the browser using `window.location.href` property:

```
var currentUrl = window.location.href;
```

If you absolutely need the rewritten url, it is the server that needs to pass it to the client. So basically when genrating the markup of your page you could use the server side language to dynamically emit it to a javascript variable.

Comment: client vs. server instructions make sense to me now.  I have come up with an htaccess approach which does the redirect nicely, but I am not sure how I can make the "new" url appear in the browser instead of the original site domain.  My htaccess code is in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947506/what-is-needed-to-have-redirected-url-appear-in-browser-address-bar-instead-of-o

Comment: As explained in my answer, since the server has access to the rewritten url, it is your server side script that can pass it to javascript.