# What is needed to have redirected URL appear in browser address bar instead of original site URL?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My htaccess is configured correctly to redirect visitors from apples.com to oranges.com, but what do I need to add so that instead of oranges.com appearing in the browser address bar, the user sees apples.com?

Update: As an alternative how can I have htaccess create a variable (such as apples) that can be picked up by javascript?

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.apples.com$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^apples.com$
rewriterule ^domainchange\/$ "http\:\/\/oranges\.com\/" [R=301,L] #numbers
rewritecond %{HTTPS} off
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oranges.com$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oranges.com$
rewriterule ^$ "https\:\/\/oranges\.com\/" [R=301,L] #numbers


Options -Indexes
```

Comment: That may not be possible without setting Apache up as a reverse proxy, or sucky solutions like an `<iframe>`. Are apples.com and oranges.com on the same server?

Comment: Yes, they are on the same server.(hosted by godaddy)

Comment: Can't you just set up apples.com as an alias of oranges.com then?

Comment: When I utilize the alias, through my godaddy account settings, javascript does not recognize the alias (apples.com) which therefore prevents me from my ultimate goal which is dynamic text based on the URL visible in the browser address bar.

Comment: What domain does Javascript think it's on?

Comment: Javascript thinks it is on oranges.com.

Comment: Pekka, do you know how the htaccess should be written for the alias?

Comment: If the domains aren't aliased to each other on the server configuration level, it's possible there is no way to rewrite the URLs transparently from one domain to the other via .htaccess. The easiest way would be if GoDaddy allowed some real aliasing, i.e. connecting apples.com directly to the directory location that is served by oranges.com. Failing that, maybe there is another way altogether to achieve what you want to achieve - you'd have to elaborate on your situation for hints on that.

Comment: Can you get `mod_proxy` enabled from GoDaddy?